# How to access hash's key as an object attribute

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have a `w_data` hash

```
 {"latitude"=>"40.695", "air_temperature"=>"-10", "longitude"=>"-96.854", "datetime"=>"2014-01-01 02:55:00"}
```

I want to access it's value by `w_data.latitude` rather than `w_data["latitude"]`

How to do it?

Comment: If it's just `latitude`, you could simply define a method by that name on the `Hash` class: `class Hash; def latitude; self["latitude"]; end; end`. Then `w_data.latitude #=> "40.695"`. If you want to do it for all keys, loop on the keys and use `define_method`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a good idea. If you do this, you've got to make sure no key has a name (after `to_s`) that is the same as the name of a method a hash responds to (`keys`, `values`, `first`, etc.).

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to say *don't* use OpenStruct, because it [nukes the method cache every time you create a new one](https://github.com/charliesome/charlie.bz/blob/master/posts/things-that-clear-rubys-method-cache.md).

Instead, consider a gem like [hashie-mash](https://github.com/intridea/hashie), or roll your own hash-alike:

`Hashie::Mash`:

```
hsh = Hashie::Mash.new("latitude"=>"40.695", "air_temperature"=>"-10", "longitude"=>"-96.854", "datetime"=>"2014-01-01 02:55:00")
hsh.latitude
 => "40.695"
```

Custom solution:

```
class AccessorHash < Hash
  def method_missing(method, *args)
    s_method = method.to_s
    if s_method.match(/=$/) && args.length == 1
      self[s_method.chomp("=")] = args[0]
    elsif args.empty? && key?(s_method)
      self.fetch(s_method)
    elsif args.empty? && key?(method)
      self.fetch(method)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end

hsh = AccessorHash.new("latitude"=>"40.695", "air_temperature"=>"-10", "longitude"=>"-96.854", "datetime"=>"2014-01-01 02:55:00")
hsh.latitude # => "40.695"
hsh.air_temperature = "16"
hsh => # {"latitude"=>"40.695", "air_temperature"=>"16", "longitude"=>"-96.854", "datetime"=>"2014-01-01 02:55:00"}
```

Comment: I am going say that's the gem I was going to recommend. +1

Answer (score 6):

If you want a pure Ruby solution, just crack open the Hash class and upgrade the `method_missing` method!

```
class Hash
  def method_missing method_name, *args, &block
    return self[method_name] if has_key?(method_name)
    return self[$1.to_sym] = args[0] if method_name.to_s =~ /^(.*)=$/

    super
  end
end
```

Now, every hash has this ability.

```
hash = {:five => 5, :ten => 10}
hash[:five]  #=> 5
hash.five  #=> 5

hash.fifteen = 15
hash[:fifteen]  #=> 15
hash.fifteen  #=> 15
```

`method_missing` is available in every Ruby class, to catch attempted calls for methods that don't (yet) exist. I've turned this into a blog post (with interactive Codewars kata) here:

http://www.rubycuts.com/kata-javascript-object

Comment: That's a good suggestion. however, it won't work in the case of a string key. But, you can solve that by adding another line: `return self[method_name.to_s] if has_key?(method_name.to_s)` :-)

Comment: Yeah, you can expand it here, but I wanted to give a solution that was easy to understand. A few more lines of ruby-foo would make it a little more robust :)

Answer (score 2):

Convert hash into an OpenStruct. Here:

```
require 'ostruct'
w_data = OpenStruct.new
hash = {"latitude"=>"40.695", "air_temperature"=>"-10", "longitude"=>"-96.854", "datetime"=>"2014-01-01 02:55:00"}
w_data.marshal_load(hash)
w_data.longitude
#=> "-96.854"
```

Another simpler way:

```
require 'ostruct'
hash = {"latitude"=>"40.695", "air_temperature"=>"-10", "longitude"=>"-96.854", "datetime"=>"2014-01-01 02:55:00"}
w_data = OpenStruct.new(hash)
w_data.longitude
#=> "-96.854"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Ruby on Rails, you can leverage the [ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/OrderedOptions.html) module to access hash keys as properties. This module extends the functionality of a regular hash, allowing you to access its keys using dot notation.

Additionally, you can use [ActiveSupport::InheritableOptions](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/InheritableOptions.html) to create a new object by passing an existing hash to it. So you are good to go.

as example show:

```rb
h = ActiveSupport::InheritableOptions.new({ girl: 'Mary', boy: 'John' })
h.girl # => 'Mary'
h.boy
```